# How to change React Native cursor color?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using React Native and I would like to change the cursor color of a text input. I actually got the default blue color.

How can I set a global color either in JavaScript or in AppDelegate ?

Comment: what do you mean by cursor color? the color of the highlight on an input? the color of your mouse cursor when hovering over an input? the color of the text input caret where you type letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we can do it by setting tint color.

In `AppDelegate.m` of project.

Adding the below code between `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];` and `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`, you can change the global tint color.

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Here is your color.
```

Or, adding the below code after `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`, you can change the tint color of TextInput/UITextField.

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Nothing happens when you change the UITextView's tint color.

And I couldn't find a way to implement it with a style of JaveScript.

Comment: In case someone wants to add a hex color, you can use [this site](http://uicolor.io/#/hex-to-ui) to convert from hex to iOS UIColor.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this on Android?

Comment: For Android see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752902/react-native-android-styling-textinput. Adding support for tintColor for both platforms is an open issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1685.

Comment: That color converter link doesn't work, try this one: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/web-color-to-uicolor-convertor/ (or use a macro per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string)

Comment: You should remember that selectionColor also changes color of selection and not only cursor!

Comment: This solution is easy and fast.

Answer (score 228):

There is actually a prop doing this for TextInput : **selectionColor**

```
<TextInput
  selectionColor={'green'}
/>
```

Here is the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#selectioncolor).

Comment: Indeed it should be the accepted answer. I'm trying to avoid using native code at the moment, and having to go native to change the color of a text input is ridiculous.

Comment: currently the   'selectionColor'   applies as a backgroud when you select the text

Comment: It only changes the cursor for iOS in current 0.63.4.

Comment: when using with current expo project, works with ios and android, but not react native web (for react native web  if use tailwindcss-react-native, can use something like "caret-black")

Comment: It's not working on my Huawei Android 9 EMUI 9.1.0, but it is on Samsung Android 14 One UI 6.0

Answer (score 27):

Best way to accomplish this, if you want consistence trough the app is putting the bellow code in your root file (index.js)

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'
TextInput.defaultProps.selectionColor = 'white'

/*class....*/
```

Answer (score 16):

Many here suggested using `selectionColor`:

```js
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';
TextInput.defaultProps.selectionColor = 'red';
```

As of RN 0.63, this solution is still inefficient for at least two reasons:

1. On Android, highlighted text gets the same bright color as the cursor, and the drop-shaped guides below highlighted text are still stuck with the default color;
2. Any input field or textarea embedded in `WebView` components will get the default cursor color on both platforms.

Therefore, the right way to change the cursor color is by editing the native settings instead.

#### Android

Go to `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` and add the following lines to the custom section:

```
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">#FF9999</item>
```

#### iOS

Go to `ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.m` and before `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` add:

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1];
```

Finally, rebuild the apps to see the result of your edits.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Why using props everywhere when we can do it with two lines for the entire app.

Comment: it's worked for me ,tks

Answer (score 10):

You can just change the **cursor color** by changing the selection color according to the documentation as shown bellow,

```
<Input 
  ...
  selectionColor={"black"}
 />
```

Comment: It's not work on Android

Answer (score 0):

**For React Native 0.62 +**

```
import {TextInput } from 'react-native'

TextInput.defaultProps = TextInput.defaultProps || {};
TextInput.defaultProps.selectionColor = 'transparent';
```

Add these line before Main function call in App.js

Eg :-

```
..Other code

TextInput.defaultProps = TextInput.defaultProps || {};
TextInput.defaultProps.selectionColor = 'transparent';

const App = () => {

...Other code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
   cursorColor="color_name"
```

in the TextInput

Answer (score 0):

selectionColor="red"

by using above code, you'll get red color of "|" in search box/text input.

For example :

```
<TextInput style={styles.searchInput}placeholder="Search Vehicle" placeholderTextColor="#868687" value={search} selectionColor="red" onChangeText={setSearch}/>
```